# Unable to get json_decode() output

Tags: php, json

I am trying to decode a simple json string POSTed to  a php file.

```
<?php

$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data_back = json_decode($jsonData, true);

echo $jsonData;
echo $data_back;

?>
```

I tested this by POSTing this sample JSON 
{"sensorid": SS0023, "x": 475, "y":212} with application/json Content-Type.

But it is returning the $jsonData values only. json_decode isn't doing anything and returning null. 
Help ?

Comment: try printing $jsonData, using var_dump($jsonData); exit; and check if you are receiving the json string properly

Comment: 'php://input'... i think your path and file name is incorrect. check file name extension like this ('my_project/my_json_file.json');

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Unquoted string.

Comment: change your file path

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Answer (score 1):

your json format must be like this

```
{"sensorid": "SS0023", "x": "475", "y":"212"}
```